# Can the styling of the users with hi rep be fixed so it doesn't wrap?

Tags: bug

Apologies if this has already been reported / covered / ignored, I couldn't see anything in the suggested posts.

Currently if a user has lots of rep with many badges, the styling is off and it's vexing - the bronze badge count drops.

There appears to be plenty of room (even with the edited message in place) so could we have it all in line please? We'll look to Mr Skeet as an example (and to be honest, he's probably the only one suffering from this ...).

[image]

p.s Personally, I've been holding off getting my 7658 bronze badges until it wraps properly...

Comment: The issue here is that no matter how big you make the box, Jon will ALWAYS end up overflowing it at some point lol

Comment: Amen to that :D

Comment: Sorry @Shog9 - Didn't see that one. It's shame that after 15 months a simple styling fix hasn't been done but we've re-designed a top navigation bar that wasn't broken ...